# PostNotificationName Exception from inside shouldSelectViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tab bar has a log-out button which displays the login screen immediately when tapped.

I want to put up a confirm Logout alert before leaving the current tab view and so added the following code to the beginning of the shouldSelectViewController block:

```
if(viewController == mLogoutCont) {
    // Post notification to initiate showing the logout confirmation alert.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"confirmLogout" object:self  userInfo:nil];
    return false;
}
```

The app crashes inside the postNotificationName call with the following NSException error:

```
2015-04-29 09:40:59.333 TestApplication[5420:210308] -[NSConcreteNotification presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe17217cc60
2015-04-29 09:40:59.341 TestApplication[5420:210308] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe17217cc60'
```

If I comment out the postNotificationName line, the app does not crash when the "LogOut" tab button is tapped – nothing visually changes on the screen – which is the expected behavior because of the `return false;`.

Comment: What's the method observing this notification?

Comment: Where is the code that process that notification? Can I see it?

Comment: Your comments led me to re-review the routine being called when the notification is caught. This routine displays an alert and requires a valid ViewController on which to present the alert.  I was not passing in the current viewController to this routine - hence the NSException.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code shown here. The only thing I can tell you is

- It's fairly bad app design to have a log out button in the tabs
  of a tab bar controller
- `[NSConcreteNotification presentViewController:animated:completion:]` indicates you're calling
  presentViewController on the notification object being passed (where 
  ever you're handling the response to the notification).

Comment: I agree that the LogOut button should not be in the tabs of a tab bar controller. Unfortunately, I am taking over the release of an app that was not designed or developed by me and I cannot make design changes at this stage.

Comment: That's understandable (and I've been there and done that *sigh), but you're log definitely indicates that the crash is called by using a notification object (rather a viewController) to perform the presentViewController selector. Check the object class that responds to this notification and calls that selector.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have the alert working now when the "LogOut" button is tapped on the tabBar. Thanks to @Ricardo and @Larme for getting me to review the routine being called once the notification is caught.
The reason for the the crash was that the current viewController was not being passed properly into the `logoutConfirmationAlert` and the NSException occurred when `presentViewController` was called.
Here's the routine called when the notification is caught:

```
-(void)logoutConfirmationAlert {
NSLog(@"Entered logoutConfirmationAlert");
UIAlertController* alert;
alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Log Out Confirmation"
                                            message:@"Please confirm that you wish to log out"
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Log Out" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                          // [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                          NSLog(@"Log Out");

                                                          [self signOut];
                                                      }];

UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                         NSLog(@"Cancel");

                                                     }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[alert addAction:cancelAction];

NSLog(@"Before  presentViewController");

[mCurrentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

NSLog(@"Presented alert");
}
```

I store the current view controller in `mCurrentViewController` before the notification is posted.

One further question I have is whether it would be appropriate to pass a reference to the current ViewController as a dictionary item in the `userInfo` parameter of `postNotificationName`?